# IndexError while trying to plot nc file with basemap

Tags: python, netcdf

I'm currently trying to plot data from an nc file containing IASI satellite's images of radiances of N2O gas in the atmosphere  I work with netcdf4, numpy, matplotlib librairies.

Problem is , I get an indexError coming from my m.contour input variables :  X and Y must be the same length as Z of the same array saize of Z and idk how to plot that according to my data : X,Y = longtitude, latitude = 1D arrays or lisst of 235586 elements and Z = 2d array 235586*14

Here is the code :

```
import netCDF4 as nc
import numpy as np
import matplotlib.colors as mcolors
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
from mpl_toolkits.basemap import Basemap, cm, shiftgrid, addcyclic #     mapping

# Open nc file

filePath = 'C:\\Users\\Lucas\\Documents\\ProjetN2O\\iasi_ret_L2_n2o_ch4_2019_05_02.nc'
ds = nc.Dataset(filePath)
print(ds)

# lat,long,time,N20,avk,Surf_P : paramètres d'interêt

# Print metadata as python dictionary
#print(ds.__dict__)

#Print dimensions and var of the dataset
for dimension in ds.dimensions.values():
    print(dimension)
for var in ds.variables.values():
    print(var)


## Extraction of variables in numpy array

temps = np.array(ds.variables["time"])
latitude = np.array(ds.variables["lat"])
longitude = np.array(ds.variables["lon"])
n2O_r = np.array(ds.variables["n2o_retrieval"])
n2O_avk = np.array(ds.variables["n2o_AVK"])
n2O_ap = np.array(ds.variables["n2o_apriori"])
SurfP = np.array(ds.variables["Surf_P"])
SurfPid = np.array(ds.variables["Surf_P_id"])
#Select a portion of the rows index cause to many rows to plot in     n2O_r

A = n2O_r[0:235587, 0:1] #All values in the 1st row
B = A.ravel()# resize to a 1D-array

# Plot variables
lat0 = 0; lon0 = 0 #lat et long 0
lon_max = longitude.max(); lon_min = longitude.min() #lat lon max
lat_max =  latitude.max(); lat_min = latitude.min()

#Plot options
m = Basemap(projection='cyl',lat_0=lat0,lon_0=lon0,resolution='c',## Projection
llcrnrlat=lat_min,urcrnrlat=lat_max,\
 llcrnrlon=lon_min,urcrnrlon=lon_max)
m.drawcoastlines(linewidth=1.2, linestyle='solid', color='k', antialiased=1,\
 zorder=2)
m.drawcountries()
m.drawlsmask(land_color='none', ocean_color='aqua', zorder=1)
viridis =plt.get_cmap('viridis', 12)

cs = m.contour(latitude,longitude,B,1000,linewidths=1.5,cmap=viridis, \
           colors='b', alpha=0.3)
```

I tried to reshape all the inputs for the plot into the same dimensions but still can't get rid of the error

error :

> Traceback (most recent call last):
> File "C:\Users\Lucas\Documents\Projet N2O\Plot.py", line 70, in 
> cs = m.contour(latitude,longitude,n2O_r,1000,linewidths=1.5,cmap=viridis, 
> File "C:\Users\Lucas\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python38\lib\site-packages\mpl_toolkits\basemap_*init*_.py", line 549, in with_transform
> return plotfunc(self,x,y,data,*args,**kwargs)
> File "C:\Users\Lucas\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python38\lib\site-packages\mpl_toolkits\basemap_*init*_.py", line 3570, in contour
> xx = x[x.shape[0]//2,:]
> IndexError: too many indices for array: array is 1-dimensional, but 2 were indexed

Variables :
[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/o0jwA.jpg)

Comment: [Please do not upload images of code/data/errors.](//meta.stackoverflow.com/q/285551)

Comment: Instead please copy the code or errors and paste them into the question as a [formatted code block](/help/formatting)

Comment: Oh ok sure i'm doing it